# How can we remove the default blue background from items in a custom list?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I created a custom list of items that are numbered. My concern is that when I call the list to the front page some of the items have a blue background. Is there a way to remove this? Can we add a style code/css within the content editor web part and 
hide it so it removes the blue background?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert the SharePoint list of items in something else(i don't know what you are using). What i mean is just put them in a variable as string elements and you wont have to worry about the back ground anymore.

Comment: Thanks! but I am not at liberty to use anything other than a SharePoint list to create pages. 
The lists are maintained at the back end and I call them on to a page using a list view web part.
Can you suggest another solution?

Comment: Well, i think you can still modify the data on your end before you post it in the web page. Thought I need to do try somethings out before I can say for sure.